# QueryDSL web support on custom controller POST request

Tags: spring-data-rest, querydsl

I would like to create a custom controller in Spring Data Rest with a QueryDSL predicate. I have 3 requirements: a body, headers and query a filter on the result.

It searches resources based on

The URL will be:

**POST** `/geosearch?type=a` with body `{"geo": {..geojson..}}` and with header `crs=crs-value`.

```
@RepositoryRestController
@RequestMapping("/geo")
public class GeoController {
    ...
    ...
    @PostMapping(value = "geosearch", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity customFind(@QuerydslPredicate(root = Domain.class) Predicate predicate,
         @RequestBody GeoRequest geoRequest,
         @RequestHeader("someheader") String someHeader) throws HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException {}
```

I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.querydsl.core.types.Predicate]: Specified class is an interface
```

suppose the controller does not accept query parameters

Comment: Found out that a @RestController solves the problem. I don't know why.

Comment: You simply change @RepositoryRestController to @RestController? Or what?..

Comment: Yes, it solved my problem.

Comment: Thanks. May be there is a repo on Github with example?..